# App crashed on listview.getSelectedItem() (ListView inside Dialog) Android

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have a dialog screen and inside the dialog I have a listview. I want to show which item is clicked from the listview by a toast message. So I tried to display a message of the clicked item by a toast message using listview.getSelectedItem().toString() but it crashed when clicked on the list item. But no crash happen if I simply display a string by toast when an item is clicked in the listview. for eg:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But crashed in the below code:

```
private void showDialer()
{
    //DIALOG SCREEN
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActionModes.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialer_dialog);

    final ListView book_list = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listBooks);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter_booklist = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter_booklist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            book_list.setAdapter(adapter_booklist);  

            book_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, book_list.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });              
    dialog.show();   
}
```

LOGCAT

> 06-02 23:53:34.521: I/class com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ExternalDbOpenHelper(8581): Database already exists
>   06-02 23:53:35.321: W/KeyCharacterMap(8581): No keyboard for id -1
>   06-02 23:53:35.321: W/KeyCharacterMap(8581): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: W/dalvikvm(8581): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8830)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionModes$2.onItemClick(ActionModes.java:87)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1702)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
>   06-02 23:53:41.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Show Us LogCat..please!!

Comment: @Roon13 I have posted the LogCat

Comment: What is `ActionModes.java:87`?

Comment: that's `Toast.makeText(ActionModes.this, book_list.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: `book_list.getSelectedItem()` is returning null. Have you debugged your file?

Comment: lisMathwizard answer should work

Comment: @Roon13 Thanks for your time got it work as suggested by lisMathwizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when you click an item in a listview, it doesn't immediately change its state to *selected*. You should get the item in the following way:

```
book_list.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, check if `book_list.getSelectedItem()` is `null`.

Next you want to do a `book_list.getItemAtPosition(pos)`